# Returning a single row from query joining multi-row tables

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a database design that holds data about houses.  There are 2 (relevant) tables - one holds property code, name, description etc, and the second holds information about attributes of the property.

Currently I have got columns in the property table (MaxDoubles, MaxSingles etc) that hold denormalised data that I need to now hold (for various reasons) in the attributes table. In effect I am swapping a series of columns in the Properties table for a series of rows in the Attributes table. So my existing query

SELECT MaxDoubles, MaxSingles 
FROM Properties

that returns one row per property needs re-writing to also produce one row per property when joined to the Attributes. If I try

SELECT A.MaxDoubles, A.MaxSingles 
FROM Properties P, Attributes A

then I obviously get multiple rows returned per property.

Is there a clever way of joining these tables so the query result returns a single row?

Thanks

Comment: Please give us the table definitions. Also, your second query is at the very least missing the WHERE clause to join properly -- or, preferably, do Properties As P Inner Join Attributes As A On P.blah = A.blah. The comma notation has been deprecated for about 18 years now.

Comment: We need to see the schema of `Attributes`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a schema like @Konerak's example, you'll need to "pivot" the attributes records if you want one row containing a property and all of its attributes.

Fortunately, [there is no shortage](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+pivot) of info on SO about how to do that. :)

Answer (score 1):

What you now have is called an [EAV data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) and what you want to do is called "to pivot". Besides using a subselect, there are two possibilities.

Using a GROUP BY:

```
SELECT P.Property_ID,
       MAX(IF(A.Type = 'maxsingles',A.Value,0)) AS MaxSingles,
       MAX(IF(A.Type = 'maxdoubles',A.Value,0)) AS MaxDoubles
FROM Properties P
JOIN Attributes A USING (Property_ID)
GROUP BY Property_ID
```

Using one JOIN for each attribute:

```
SELECT P.Property_ID, A1.Value AS MaxSingles, A2.Value AS MaxDoubles
FROM Properties P
JOIN Attributes A1 ON (A1.Property_ID = P.Property_ID AND A1.Type = 'maxsingles')
JOIN Attributes A2 ON (A2.Property_ID = P.Property_ID AND A2.Type = 'maxdoubles')
```

Answer (score 0):

We'll need more information from you to handle your question. For example:

What do your tables look like (`SHOW CREATE TABLE Properties`)
What queries do you want to execute?
How do you join your tables?

This schema is normalized enough to allow typical all queries:

**Table Properties:**

- PropertyID
- PropertyName
- Propertydescription

**Table Attributes:**

- AttributeID
- PropertyID
- AttributeName
- AttributeValue

So if you have Property 1, a white house with 3 bedrooms, you could have

```
PropertyID: 1
PropertyName: Charming white landhouse with 3 spacious bedrooms
Propertydescription: This charming landhouse will ...

Attributes
AttributeID: 1
PropertyID: 1
AttributeName: NrBedrooms
AttributeValue: 3

AttributeID: 2
PropertyID: 1
AttributeName: NrBathrooms
AttributeValue: 2

AttributeID: 3
PropertyID: 1
AttributeName: Kitchen
AttributeValue: Fully Equiped
```

Now if you want to know how many bedrooms your house has, you can ask

```
SELECT A.AttributeValue from Attributes A
INNER JOIN Properties P
ON P.PropertyID = A.PropertyID
WHERE P.PropertyID = 1
and A.AttributeName = 'NrBedrooms'
```