# Creating one resultset from multiple join tables; columns are comprised of a lookup table

Tags: sql, mysql

Does anyone know if it is possible to write a query that can produce the following output based on the below tables?

I have managed to create the below results by creating three separate queries and passing the previous queries' result set into the next query. But I was hoping for a more efficient way.

***I want this output using ONE SQL if possible?***

```
          baseball  computer  laptop
Jane Doe  5                  
Joe Blogs           8         8
```

***These are the tables I have to work with:***

persons table

```
id    first_name  last_name
101   Jane        Doe
576   Joe         Blogs
```

hobbies table

```
id hobby_type   hours_spent
1  sports       5
2  technology   8
```

hobby_types table

```
id name
33 computer
39 baseball
45 laptop
```

persons_hobbies join-table for person and hobbies

```
id person_id hobby_id
1  101      1
3  576      1
2  576      2
```

hobbies_hobby_types join-table for hobbies and hobby_types

```
hobby_id hobby_type_id 
1        39
2        33
3        45
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to get a so-called [pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156877/returning-a-single-row-from-query-joining-multi-row-tables/4157034#4157034).

I'm afraid there is no way to do it in MySQL with an unlimited number of columns, but maybe I'm wrong. Use your newly learned keyword to find a lot of information on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

As AndreKR says, you can't do this in a single select in MySQL with an unlimited number of columns, but if the column values are known in advance, then you could do it with a query like this:

```
select person_name,
       sum(case hobby_type when 'baseball' then hours_spent else 0 end) baseball,
       sum(case hobby_type when 'computer' then hours_spent else 0 end) computer,
       sum(case hobby_type when 'laptop' then hours_spent else 0 end)   laptop
from
(select p.first_name + ' ' + p.last_name person_name,
        ht.name                          hobby_type,
        h.hours_spent
 from persons p
 join persons_hobbies ph on p.id = ph.person_id
 join hobbies h on ph.hobby_id = h.id
 join hobbies_hobby_types hht on h.id = hht.hobby_id
 join hobby_types ht on hht.hobby_type_id = ht.id) sq
group by person_name
```

Incidentally, if the table structures in your database are remotely similar to those in the example, you should seriously reconsider them. Hours spent would normally be allocated at the person-hobby join level - here, it looks as though you are taking the total hours spent per hobby and allocating all of them to each person, causing serious overcounting. A similar concern also applies to the Hobby-Types to Hobbies relationship.