# Query by Value in Adjacent Column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, join, union, entity-attribute-value

I believe all questions of this nature start out this way... 
*I have two tables*: `fields` and `data`. `Fields` describes the column names of a (non-existant) table and `data` contains the data of that (non-existant) table. Like so...

Fields:

```
    +----+---------+-------------+---------------+-------+----------+
    | ID | F_ORDER | NAME        | LABEL         | VALUE | TYPE     |
    +----+---------+-------------+---------------+-------+----------+
    |  1 |       1 | IS_EMPLOYEE | Region        |       | checkbox |
    |  2 |       3 | EM_AVATAR   | Avatar        |       | avatar   |
    |  3 |       4 | EM_JOBTITLE | Job Title     |       | text     |
    |  4 |       5 | EM_COMPANY  | Company       |       | text     |
    |  5 |       6 | EM_PHONE    | Phone         |       | text     |
    |  6 |       2 | EM_ORDER    | Display Order | 5     | text     |
    +----+---------+-------------+---------------+-------+----------+
```

Data:

```
    +-----+----------+---------+--------------------------------------+
    | ID  | FIELD_ID | USER_ID | VALUE                                |
    +-----+----------+---------+--------------------------------------+
    |   5 |        1 |       1 | YES                                  |
    |   6 |        2 |       1 |                                      |
    |   7 |        3 |       1 | Owner                                |
    |   8 |        4 |       1 | Acme, Inc.                           |
    |   9 |        5 |       1 | 123-456-7987                         |
    | 150 |        5 |      31 | 123-623-5555                         |
    | 149 |        4 |      31 | Acme, Inc.                           |
    | 148 |        3 |      31 | Sales and Customer Support           |
    | 147 |        2 |      31 |                                      |
    | 146 |        1 |      31 | YES                                  |
    |  26 |        1 |       6 | NO                                   |
    |  27 |        2 |       6 | http://example.com/avi/avi.jpeg      |
    |  28 |        3 |       6 | CEO                                  |
    |  29 |        4 |       6 | Acme                                 |
    |  30 |        5 |       6 | (123) 734-5555                       |
    |  31 |        1 |       7 | NO                                   |
    |  32 |        2 |       7 | http://example.com/avi/avi.jpeg      |
    |  33 |        3 |       7 | VP, Services                         |
    |  34 |        4 |       7 | Acme                                 |
    |  35 |        5 |       7 | (913) 963-5555                       |
    |  36 |        1 |      14 | NO                                   |
    |  37 |        2 |      14 | http://example.com/avi/avi.jpeg      |
    |  38 |        3 |      14 | Senior Accountant                    |
    |  39 |        4 |      14 | Acme                                 |
    |  40 |        5 |      14 | (123) 213-5555                       |
    |  41 |        1 |      10 | NO                                   |
    |  42 |        2 |      10 | http://example.com/avi/avi.jpeg      |
    |  43 |        3 |      10 | President                            |
    |  44 |        4 |      10 | Acme                                 |
    |  45 |        5 |      10 | (123) 734-5555                       |
    |  46 |        1 |      12 | NO                                   |
    |  47 |        2 |      12 | http://example.com/avi/avi.jpeg      |
    |  48 |        3 |      12 | Services Supervisor                  |
    |  49 |        4 |      12 | Acme                                 |
    |  50 |        5 |      12 | (123) 573-5555                       |
    |  51 |        1 |      11 | NO                                   |
    |  52 |        2 |      11 | http://example.com/avi/avi.jpeg      |
    |  53 |        3 |      11 | Operations Supervisor                |
    |  54 |        4 |      11 | Acme                                 |
    |  55 |        5 |      11 | (123) 259-5555                       |
    |  56 |        1 |       8 | NO                                   |
    |  57 |        2 |       8 | http://example.com/avi/avi.jpeg      |
    |  58 |        3 |       8 | General Information                  |
    |  59 |        4 |       8 | Acme                                 |
    |  60 |        5 |       8 | (123) 213-5555                       |
    |  61 |        1 |       9 | NO                                   |
    |  62 |        2 |       9 | http://example.com/avi/avi.jpeg      |
    |  63 |        3 |       9 | VP, Sales                            |
    |  64 |        4 |       9 | Acme                                 |
    |  65 |        5 |       9 | (123) 210-5555                       |
    +-----+----------+---------+--------------------------------------+
```

The basic verbiage of the query I'm looking for is: I want all information for all people who are employees (`IS_EMPLOYEE = "YES"`) and ordered by their display order column (`EM_ORDER`).

My query so far gets me nowhere. I get results a little like this:

```
    +--------+------------+------------+-------+---------+-------+
     ID        FIELD_ID    NAME         LABEL   TYPE       VALUE
    +--------+------------+------------+-------+---------+-------+
     7         1           IS_EMPLOYEE  Region  checkbox   YES
    +--------+------------+------------+-------+---------+-------+
```

What I need are results like this:

```
    +-------+------------+---------+-----------+----------+-------------+--------+
     USER_ID IS_EMPLOYEE  EM_AVATAR EM_JOBTITLE EM_COMPANY EM_PHONE      EM_ORDER   
    +-------+------------+---------+-----------+----------+-------------+--------+
     6       YES           http://  CEO         Acme       123-123-555   5 
    +-------+------------+---------+-----------+----------+-------------+--------+
```

And of course I'm trying to get it all back into PHP as a usable array (`$results['user_id']['jobtitle']` etc.). I could just get **everything** and work through it with PHP, but I'm trying to learn MySQL and I think this is a faster method than doing several foreach blocks ... although I could be wrong.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Can the data table have multiple values for the same field same user? (ie: what's your cardinality?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Returning a single row from query joining multi-row tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156877/returning-a-single-row-from-query-joining-multi-row-tables)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the possible duplicate. I've been searching on here all day for ideas. But when you really, **really** don't know what type of solution you are looking for, it's tough to spot them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically a `PIVOT` but MySQL does not have a `PIVOT` function so you can replicate it using an aggregate function and a `CASE` statement.

A Static version is when you know all of the values that you want to transform into columns (these are your field names):

```
select 
  d.user_id,
  max(case when f.name = 'IS_EMPLOYEE' then d.value else null end) IS_EMPLOYEE,
  max(case when f.name = 'EM_AVATAR' then d.value else null end) EM_AVATAR,
  max(case when f.name = 'EM_JOBTITLE' then d.value else null end) EM_JOBTITLE,
  max(case when f.name = 'EM_COMPANY' then d.value else null end) EM_COMPANY,
  max(case when f.name = 'EM_PHONE' then d.value else null end) EM_PHONE,
  max(case when f.name = 'EM_ORDER' then d.value else null end) EM_ORDER
from data d
left join fields f
  on f.id = d.FIELD_ID
group by d.user_id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c7ee3/9)

Result:

```
| USER_ID | IS_EMPLOYEE |                       EM_AVATAR |                EM_JOBTITLE | EM_COMPANY |       EM_PHONE | EM_ORDER |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|       1 |         YES |                          (null) |                      Owner | Acme, Inc. |   123-456-7987 |   (null) |
|       6 |          NO | http://example.com/avi/avi.jpeg |                        CEO |       Acme | (123) 734-5555 |   (null) |
|       7 |          NO | http://example.com/avi/avi.jpeg |               VP, Services |       Acme | (913) 963-5555 |   (null) |
|       8 |          NO | http://example.com/avi/avi.jpeg |        General Information |       Acme | (123) 213-5555 |   (null) |
|       9 |          NO | http://example.com/avi/avi.jpeg |                  VP, Sales |       Acme | (123) 210-5555 |   (null) |
|      10 |          NO | http://example.com/avi/avi.jpeg |                  President |       Acme | (123) 734-5555 |   (null) |
|      11 |          NO | http://example.com/avi/avi.jpeg |      Operations Supervisor |       Acme | (123) 259-5555 |   (null) |
|      12 |          NO | http://example.com/avi/avi.jpeg |        Services Supervisor |       Acme | (123) 573-5555 |   (null) |
|      14 |          NO | http://example.com/avi/avi.jpeg |          Senior Accountant |       Acme | (123) 213-5555 |   (null) |
|      31 |         YES |                          (null) | Sales and Customer Support | Acme, Inc. |   123-623-5555 |   (null) |
```

If you have an unknown number of values to turn into columns, then you can use a prepared statement to generate the sql dynamically.

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when f.name = ''',
      name,
      ''' then d.value end) AS ',
      name
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM fields;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT d.user_id, ', @sql, ' 
                  from data d
                  left join fields f
                    on f.id = d.FIELD_ID
                   GROUP BY d.user_id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c7ee3/11)

Both will produce the same result.

You can then add a `WHERE` clause to filter out any of the unneeded rows.

Comment: Just know that this doesn't work well if you have multiple values per field/user.

Comment: @marvin but, there are ways to implement this type of query if you have multiple records per user.

Comment: If you have multiple values for a specific field for the same user, the max is only going to choose one, right?  This type of pivoting is handy, I've used it before, but in some situations like the multiple values per field, it doesn't work so well.  Right?

Comment: @marvin for example, if this was data entered by a user but there were multiple dates associated with the entries, then you could technically group by the date as well which would allow for multiple rows per user.

Comment: The query is fine, taking into account the user data. He's just missing the `having` clause.

Comment: This post has been up for 10 mins. How did you write that so fast? Amazing. I will definitely work with it and see if it will work. Thanks so much for putting me in the right direction.

Comment: @Shelton it comes with practice. :)  This of course can be tweaked for any of your needs, I was just providing an example with the full data set.

Comment: Everything should be one-to-one. Each ID only has one jobtitle, one company, etc that can possibly be assigned.

Comment: @Shelton then you should not have any worries about missing records per user, since there cannot be multiple entries.

Comment: I'd add some RI to enforce it in the db though just to be safe. (You are fast BF).

Answer (score 3):

Your data table is organized in the [Entity-Attribute-Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) manner, which is not a valid way of storing relational data.  It's no wonder that it's awkward to retrieve it with SQL into a conventional row with one column per attribute.

To do this with SQL, you basically need to do a **pivot query**.  This is hard to write and terribly inefficient to execute.

You're better off fetching all the data for employees:

```
SELECT e.*, f.label
FROM Data AS is_employee
JOIN Data AS e USING (user_id)
JOIN Fields AS f ON e.field_id = f.id
WHERE (is_employee.field_id, is_employee.value) = (1, 'Yes');
```

And then reorganizing it into a collection of associative arrays in PHP code:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
  $data[ $row['user_id'] ][ $row['label'] ] = $row['value'];
}
```

Comment: That's an extremely helpful answer. Thank you. I agree that the organization is terrible, even from my novice point of view. But at this point I cannot change the structure. I may have to admit defeat - knowing when to do that is key, I suppose.